# Problems with Transaction of one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have working code , when user goes from 1 fragmeent to another, but problem is, that when New Fragment is opened, old fragment is also dispalyed under.

So user is seeing new fragment, but when he scroll down, he will also old fragment.
Is there an option, to totally hide previous fragment?

```
if(userDTO.getMobile().isEmpty()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test2, null))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.okaypopup2,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                                    ProfileSetting myFragment = new ProfileSetting();
                                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                            .replace(R.id.zopa, myFragment)
                                            //.addToBackStack(null)
                                            .commit();
                                }
                            })
                    .show();
        }
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.. i Expect to open new fragment, when popup message appears.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this statement

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.zopa, myFragment)
                                        //.addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();
```

To this

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), myFragment)
                                        //.addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();
```

I think you are passing the fragment id not the Activity container id in `replace`

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to your old Fragment, get a reference and remove it at any time that is convenient to you. Something along the lines of:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAG_TAG);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAG_TAG);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```